# Testing and coding conventions for testing C with SDL

Tags: c, unit-testing, sdl

I finished my first real C project and it was Conways Game of Life. The code is working fine and the game runs. Since this was my first project though I don't know any of the real code conventions for writing C. I wanted to implement some tests so I had to split up the functionality from the main file into a new one.

I couldn't really figure out though how to write the tests to maybe refactor the code in the future and just for educational purposes since this is my first time also writing any real tests. Since I implemented many functions that work together with the ones from SDL I have no clue how to test these. This is the file containing all functions:

```
#include "./main.h"

multi_arr Field = {0,};
multi_arr nextState = {0,};

SDL_Color blue = {0,0,255,255};
SDL_Color black = {0,0,0,255};
SDL_Color white = {244,244,244,50};

int getLastMultiple(int number){
    int multiple = RECT_SIZE;
    float remainder;
    if ((remainder = (number % multiple)) == 0)
        return number;
    else{
        number -= remainder;
    }
    return number;
}

void colorRect(SDL_Renderer *renderer, SDL_Rect r,SDL_Color color){
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, color.r, color.g, color.b ,255);

    // Render rect
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &r);
}


void drawGrid(SDL_Renderer *renderer,SDL_Color color){
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, color.r,color.g,color.b,color.a);
    for (int i = 20; i < SCREEN_WIDTH; i += 20){
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, i,0,i,SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    }
    for (int i = 20; i < SCREEN_HEIGHT;i += 20){
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 0,i,SCREEN_WIDTH,i);
    }
}

void displayImg(SDL_Renderer *renderer,char* path){
    SDL_Surface *image = SDL_LoadBMP(path);
    if (image == NULL){
        printf("cant load image\n");
    }
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image);

    SDL_Rect image_pos = { 6,SCREEN_HEIGHT-55, 50, 50 };
    SDL_Rect rect = {0,SCREEN_HEIGHT-59,60,60};

    colorRect(renderer, rect, white);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL,&image_pos);
}

void updateGame(SDL_Window *window,SDL_Renderer *renderer, SDL_Rect r,bool paused){
    //Loop through field-array and show rectangles if cell alive
    char *path;
    
    if (paused){
        path = "./assets/start.bmp";
    } else{
        path = "./assets/pause.bmp";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH;i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT;j++){
            if (Field[i][j] == true){
                r.x = i * 20;
                r.y = j * 20;
                colorRect(renderer, r, blue);
            } else {
                r.x = i * 20;
                r.y = j * 20;
                colorRect(renderer, r, white);
            }
        }
    }

    drawGrid(renderer,black);
    displayImg(renderer, path);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

int countAliveNeighbors(int x, int y){
    int count = 0;

    for (int rows = -1; rows < 2; rows++){
        for (int columns = -1; columns < 2;columns++){
            if ((x+columns) >= 0 && (x+columns) < WIDTH && (y+rows) >= 0 && (y+rows) < HEIGHT){
                if (Field[x+columns][y+rows] == true){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (Field[x][y] == true){
        return count -1;
    }
    return count;
}

void copyArray(multi_arr arr1,multi_arr arr2){
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH;i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT;j++){
            arr1[i][j] = arr2[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void nextEpoch(){
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH;i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT;j++){
            if (Field[i][j] == true && (countAliveNeighbors(i, j) == 3 || countAliveNeighbors(i, j) == 2)){
                nextState[i][j] = true;               
            } else if (Field[i][j] == false && countAliveNeighbors(i, j) == 3){
                nextState[i][j] = true;
            } else {
                nextState[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    copyArray(Field, nextState);
}


bool buttonPress(int x,int y){
    if (x <= 2 && x >= 0 && y >= (HEIGHT - 3) && y <= HEIGHT){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

Uint32 my_callbackfunc( Uint32 interval, void *param ){
    SDL_Event e;

    e.user.type = SDL_USEREVENT;
    e.user.code = 0;
    e.user.data1 = NULL;
    e.user.data2 = NULL;

    SDL_PushEvent(&e);

    return interval;
}
```

These are the tests I have written so far:

```
#include "./include/criterion/criterion.h"
#include "include/criterion/assert.h"
#include "include/criterion/internal/test.h"
#include "main.h" 

extern multi_arr Field;

Test(getLastMultiple,test_getLastMultiple_if_multiple_20){
    cr_assert(getLastMultiple(58) == 40);
    cr_assert(getLastMultiple(29) == 20);
    cr_assert(getLastMultiple(640) == 640);
}

Test(aliveNeighbors,test_count_alive_neighbors_if_cell_active){
    Field[20][10] = true;
    Field[19][10] = true;
    Field[21][11] = true;

    cr_assert(countAliveNeighbors(20, 10) == 2);
}

Test(aliveNeighbors,test_count_alive_neighbors_if_cell__not_active){
    Field[20][10] = true;
    Field[19][10] = true;
    Field[21][11] = true;

    cr_assert(countAliveNeighbors(20, 11) == 3);
}

Test(buttonPress,test_button_press_detected){
    cr_assert(buttonPress(2, HEIGHT) == true);
    cr_assert(buttonPress(5, HEIGHT) == false);
}

Test(copyArray,test_array_copied){
    Field[20][10] = true;
    Field[19][10] = true;
    Field[21][11] = true;

    multi_arr copied = {0,};

    copyArray(copied,Field);
    /*cr_assert_arrays_eq_cmp(copied,Field);*/
}

Test(nextEpoch,test_if_next_epoch_cells_correct_pos){
    int active_cells = 0;
    multi_arr nextState = {0,};

    Field[20][10] = true;
    Field[19][10] = true;
    Field[21][11] = true;

    nextEpoch();
    for (int i = 0;i < WIDTH;i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT;j++){
            active_cells += (Field[i][j] == true) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
    cr_assert(active_cells == 2);
    cr_assert(Field[20][10] == true && Field[20][11] == true);
}
```

Thanks for the help and sorry if I didn't use the community in the correct way. Any help is appreciated. This is all the code: https://github.com/PhilippRados/GameOfLife

**Any tips for improving this code are highly appreciated**